# Multiple ion-scroll both with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, ionic-framework

I have two ion scroll tags. Inside each of these ion-scroll tags is a list. Each of these lists start with 10 items, and when a user reaches the bottom of a particular ion scroll it should load more. The problem I am facing is this is quite not working correctly. If I scroll through the first it scroll window and paginate through all the items it should say no more content. This does not happen though, instead if I scroll through the second scroll window then it will load more items in the first and second ion scroll window(which I don't want). Essentially I would like the two ion scrolls to be completely independent of each other. I would like each to load it's own content. I hope that made sense. Here is my codepen:

http://codepen.io/polska03/pen/jWKRwP

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Ionic Pull to Refresh</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="ionicApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="background-places">

    <ion-view>
    <ion-content class="" scroll='false'>
        <ion-scroll style="height:50%">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item collection-repeat="list in _list">
                    <h2>Item</h2>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <button class="button button-full button-outline button-positive" ng-if="noMoreContent">
      No more Content
   </button>
            <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="canWeLoadMoreContent()" on-infinite="populateList()" distance="1%">
            </ion-infinite-scroll>
        </ion-scroll>

<hr>
<hr>

        <ion-scroll style="height:50%">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item collection-repeat="list2 in _list2">

                    <h2>Item</h2>

                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>



            <button class="button button-full button-outline button-positive" ng-if="noMoreContent2">
       No More Content
     </button>
            <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="canWeLoadMoreContent2()" on-infinite="populateList2()" distance="1%">
            </ion-infinite-scroll>
        </ion-scroll>

    </ion-content>

</ion-view>


  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {






  $scope._list = [];

  $scope.populateList = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {


      $scope._list.push({});
    }
    console.log($scope._list.length);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  }

  $scope.noMoreContent = false;

  $scope.canWeLoadMoreContent = function() {
    if($scope._list.length > 15) {
      $scope.noMoreContent = true;

      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
  $scope.populateList();





  $scope._list2 = [];

  $scope.populateList2 = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {



      $scope._list2.push({});

    }
    console.log($scope._list2.length);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  }

  $scope.noMoreContent2 = false;

  $scope.canWeLoadMoreContent2 = function() {
    if($scope._list2.length > 15) {
      $scope.noMoreContent2 = true;

      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }



  $scope.populateList2();




});
```

Comment: Is this issue resolved because i am also facing this issue ?

Comment: I have the similar situation, too. I have 1 view include 2 ion-list and how to achieve both of 2 list have it's own ion-infinite-scroll?

Comment: Having the same issue but the ionic team is not reponsive. Did you come with a solution?https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/multiple-ion-infinite-scroll/52895

Comment: No sorry, I had to redesign this component of my app as I had to produce a product before release and haven't looked into this as of then. I will look into it again though soon and if I find anything I will post the answer here. I had some luck with setting the heights equal to auto on the slide, but if I remember correctly it made the slides all he same height (the height of all the slides was the height of the biggest slide) which caused some slides with less content to have a lot of empty white space to scroll thru.

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes from the 'require' ?^ionicScroll that is not resolved properly in the directive. Not sure why, as I'm not an AngularJS expert.
That said, I found a workaround which is about inserting an extra div around the content tags, as in http://codepen.io/priand/pen/PzYbZG, if this helps someone.

```
<div>
<ion-content class="has-header col col-50">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
              item="item">
      Item {{ item.id }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
</div>

<div>
<ion-content class="has-header col col-offset-50 col-50">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items2" 
              item="item">
      Item {{ item.id }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable2" on-infinite="loadMore2()" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>      
</ion-content>
</div>
```